# Pushing out smallest repo possible, and issues with git subtree on shallow clone

Tags: git, deployment, jenkins

I'm attempting to use `git subtree pull --squash` to merge another repo as a subdirectory in my repository, called **docroot**. This is happening in a Jenkins workspace and I am trying to use a shallow clone of my repo because it is being pushed out to a remote repo to run the application. It is large when cloned with full history, so I'm trying to keep it as small as possible when pushed out. When I attempt to issue a `git subtree pull` on a shallow clone of my repository (cloned with `git clone --depth=1`), I get this error:

> Can't squash-merge: 'docroot' was never added.

If I don't use `--squash` it runs but there are conflicts which need to be resolved, which is no good for a CI job that has to run often. My goal is to push out the smallest repo possible to save on disk space. There will be multiple instances of this application pushed out so I want to keep it as small as possible. I will also look into making the repo smaller, but the largest decrease in size I've seen is possible by using a shallow clone. Maybe there is a better way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to workaround this problem by using the other repository, `docroot`, as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in the original repository. This assumes that the repo `docroot` is independent, and doesn't share any code with the parent repository.

That way, you can have a shallow clone of the parent repo, and shouldn't face any conflicts with the full `docroot` being checked out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the destination server I'm pushing out to does not support git submodules.